# Web Font Not Working Windows

Tags: css, windows, webfonts

I have my font in all of the formats known to man, and for some reason they will not load on any windows browser. Here is my code:

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'AvenirNext-Regular';
  src: url('/avenir/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.eot');
  src: url('/avenir/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/avenir/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/avenir/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/avenir/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.svg#AvenirNext-Regular') format('svg'),
       url('/avenir/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

It's probably something small but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, URLs shouldn't start with `/`, as the operating system will understand them as absolute paths. Is the `avenir` folder in the root of the site?

Comment: No, it's a wordpress site, but the avenir folder is in the same directory as the style.css. I'll try changing what you suggested and see if it works

Comment: I assume you have your fonts located in your theme's directory. So in that case the style should be something like `url('/wp-content/themes/<name-of-your-theme>/avenir/AvenirNext-Regular/AvenirNext-Regular`.

Comment: Have you tried to load the font directly by typing the URL from your browser and see what returns? To be honest the last thing that comes to my mind is a permissions issue. This is probably the case if it returns a "403: Forbidden" error.

Comment: Yeah when I do they download to my computer. How would I change the permissions

Comment: I get this in windows. It downloaded on my mac. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()